# How to install caffeine on Scientific Linux 6.3

Tags: screensaver

```
caffeine
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/caffeine", line 40, in <module>
    import caffeine
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/caffeine/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

This is what I get after installing caffeine.

```
rpm -qa | egrep -i 'caffeine|gobject'
caffeine-2.4.419-1.el6.nux.noarch
pygobject2-2.20.0-5.el6.x86_64
```

How can I install it? what am I missing?

https://launchpad.net/caffeine

Answer (score 1):

Your pygobject is too old. `gi.repository` used to be provided by [PyGI](https://live.gnome.org/PyGI). It was [merged into pygobject](http://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/commit/?id=fb1ee243493616d7a7e4f6924c574db39f5a423d), but not until 2.21.4, so you either need to update pygobject or install PyGI (probably the former)